# Validate uploaded file size in Hapi.js

Tags: hapi.js, joi

Using Joi for validation in API, is there a way we can validate and allow file size to api upto max limit.?

```
payload: {
      maxBytes: 20715200,
      output: 'stream',
      parse: true,
      allow: 'multipart/form-data',
      fileData: Joi.binary().required(),
    },
```

Still getting response -

```
{
    "statusCode": 413,
    "error": "Request Entity Too Large",
    "message": "Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
payload:{
    maxBytes: 5*1024*1024,
  },



 validate:{
    payload: {
      output: 'stream',
      parse: true,
      allow: 'multipart/form-data',
      fileData: Joi.binary().required().error(new Error("File is required")),
}
}
```

maxBytes will not be included in validate object, declare outside in seperate payload field.